# TeamViewer Android: how to connect in a unattended way?

Tags: teamviewer

My grandma is 89 years old, and I have installed **TeamViewer** on her Android tablet in order to remotely assist her.
But it is a problem for me to teach her understanding the screen messages, even when it is a single "*Accept incoming connection? Yes/No*" .

Is there any way to configure TeamViewer for Android to **connect to it without any intervention** on remote side?

- **Free**(gratis) options preferred.

Comment: Pretty sure Android's embedded security pretty much prevents this from being possible without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way it works is for you to install [TeamViewer for Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) on your device and install [TeamViewer Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market) on you grand mother device to allow unattended access. Test it after installing. Reading the comments, it seems it does not work on 100% on all devices.

Comment: A payment solution?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Another solution is Anydesk but it also requires to accept the incoming session which won't solve your case.